# while(true) vs EventWaitHandle notifications in "1000 times per second" processing

Tags: c#

I'm writing trading engine. I receive updates from market veeeeeryyyy ofthen. It's about ~1000 updates per second and I put them in queue. Taking into accout how ofthen I should process messages the question is - is it reasonable to use EventWaitHandle or it's better to use `while(true)` loop?

```
while (true)
{
    queue.wh.WaitOne(); // do I need that to be executed 1000 times per second or just skip it?
    if (queue.Count > 0)
        queue.Dequeue()
        ....
```

Or probably you can suggest something different...

Comment: Hardly often ;) I handle tens of thousands per second (5 compelte exchanges). ARe you that time sensitive? I am not - I trade millisecond upward, not high frequency.

Comment: Funny username for a C# programmer.

Comment: Jonas actually I was using Java for 7 years but now I have to use C# because it better feets my needs :) `queue` is actually written by me, but it doesn't matter in scope of this question I think.

Comment: Is your queue object accessed concurrently?

Comment: A *BlockingQueue* implementation.  http://pastebin.com/v8RDZAX7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should investigate the both of these ways.

My first version is:

```
while(true)
{
  while(queue.Count > 0)
  {
    var md;

    lock(queue)
    {
      md = queue.Dequeue();
    }

    ...    
  }

  Thread.Sleap(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`WaitOne()` is smart to enough to first use spin lock so I think you won't gain anything in performance/resources to change your code. Maybe the only thing you may do is replace your `if` with a `while` so you may process all queued requests in one "cycle".

Comment: Spin Locks utilizes by the ManualResetEventSlim only

Answer (score 0):

You could put the `WaitOne()` in an else clause.

```
if (queue.Count > 0)
    queue.Dequeue();
else
    queue.wh.WaitOne();
```